# Вопрос по поводу навигации в приложении Android

Tags: android

Я использую Navigation Library.

Первый Fragment, от которого все начинается это LoginFragment. 
Как сделать так, чтобы я не мог вернуться на этот Fragment нажатием клавиши назад?

Я могу сделать это через интерфейс (проверяя размер Backstack, и выполнять переход назад, пока размер > 2).

Как это сделать через UI Navigation?

Answer (score 2):

При навигации от логин-фрагмента нужно указать опцию `setPopUpTo` со значением `true` для второго параметра (inclusive), и тогда исходный фрагмент будет "поглощен" при возврате.

```
findNavController().navigate(
    R.id.action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment,
    null,
    NavOptions.Builder()
        .setPopUpTo(R.id.loginFragment, true)
        .build()
)
```

Аналогичный параметр для XML-разметки: `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Use action with this parameters

```
       <action
        android:id="@+id/action_registerFragment_to_homeFragment"
        app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык